# Email through Android Emulator

Tags: email, android-emulator

Can we send receive emails through Android Emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I receive gmail through my emulator all the time.

Comment: This post begs the question: How? It's not a default setting because my emulator does not do it.

Comment: @MikeS. It's been two years, so I don't remember the details exactly, but perhaps set it up like you would normally on a phone?

Answer (score 0):

In windows im able to sync my company mail in emulator(Android 4.0).I am receiving all mails,and im able to send the mails also.To sync your mail in android emulator, follow below procedure,
step1-Enable net access in your emulator
step2-go to email from apps
step3-enter your email id and password,click next
step4-there i select exchange bcoz mine is outlook exchange a/c
step5-fill the fields-
domainname/username:
Password:
Server:
enable two checkboxes-Use secure connection and Accept all SSL certificates
step6:DONE

It is working fine.

Hope this will help you...